Add axes without graduation on a defined area
I would like to be able to add axes to my graph (one in x=0, one in x=1 and a last one in y=0) without the graduations.
I have tried and either I have the axes but not the text (by putting xmin=0 for example) or I have the text but not the axes (with xmin=-0.2 and putting the text after the \end{axis} line).
How can I get my axes as desired?
\documentclass[10pt,border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\begin{document}
    
    \def\PsaturA{5.8}%ehtnaol
    \def\PsaturB{12.3}%methanol
    
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=0,ymax=15,
            xlabel=$x_B$,
            samples = 500,
            no markers,
            ticks=none,
            ]
            
            
            % tracé concentration AH3 :
            
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=red] expression[domain=0:1]{\PsaturA+(\PsaturB-\PsaturA)*x};
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=red] expression[domain=0:1]{\PsaturA*\PsaturB/(\PsaturB-(\PsaturB-\PsaturA)*x)};
            
            
            %\draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (axis cs: \Veq,-1) -- +(axis cs: 0,3);
            \draw (-0.1,\PsaturA) node{$P^*_A$};
            \draw (1.1,\PsaturB) node{$P^*_B$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

example that comes close to what I'm looking for :


Like so?

If so, I took advantage of clipping to the min/max ranges and made all lines longer than needed.
For y=0 at the moment the axis coincides with the frame, so I adjusted ymin a little bit.
If not, please add a sketch of your desired outcome to your question.
BTW, chemmacros and siunitx may be not needed here. xcolor is already loaded, if I remember correcetly.
\documentclass[10pt,border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}            % Permet l'affichage de deux axes y
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824

\begin{document}
    
    \def\PsaturA{5.8}%ehtnaol
    \def\PsaturB{12.3}%methanol
    
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=-1,ymax=15,    % <<<
            xlabel=$x_B$,
            samples = 500,
            no markers,
            ticks=none,
            ]
            
            
            % tracé concentration AH3 :
            
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=red] expression[domain=0:1]{\PsaturA+(\PsaturB-\PsaturA)*x};
            \addplot[mark=none, draw=red] expression[domain=0:1]{\PsaturA*\PsaturB/(\PsaturB-(\PsaturB-\PsaturA)*x)};
            
            
            %\draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (axis cs: \Veq,-1) -- +(axis cs: 0,3);
            \draw (-0.1,\PsaturA) node{$P^*_A$};
            \draw (1.1,\PsaturB) node{$P^*_B$};
            
            % ~~~ extra axis', utilizing clipping to min/max area ~~~~~~
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 0,-5) -- (axis cs: 0,20);
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: 1,-5) -- (axis cs: 1,20);
            \draw[dotted] (axis cs: -1,0) -- (axis cs: 2,0);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


P.S.: You could add at the end, with some trial & error:
...
            % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \node               at (axis cs: 0.5, 4)   {Label 1};
            \node[rotate=27]    at (axis cs: 0.6, 7.5) {Label A};

            \node               at (axis cs: 0.2,12)   {Label 2};
            \node[rotate=27]    at (axis cs: 0.5,10) {Label B};    
        \end{axis}


However, if you don't need the pgfplots features, such drawings are easier to do with plain Tikz. E.g. use option sloped instead of rotate.

I edited my post with an image quite similar to what I want.
I know about the packages you mention: they will be useful to me later, when I finalize

Thank you. // Unused packages will be loaded, which may e.g. require updates, even if someone here just tries to compile your example. This won’t be a problem for longtime members, but can be frustrating for new members. So it’s better to exclude what isn’t needed.

Oh yes indeed, I didn't think about this consequence: I will try to remember it for the next times

Kindly see my P.S.

thanks ; If I want to remove the frame that surrounds everything, how do I do it? I can't see which command materializes it

Use hide x axis, hide y axis, see e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728274/245790
